# How to test if cell contains specific text in formula

Tags: excel, excel-2010

Consider the following formula for cell A1

```
=Assumptions!$F$25*Assumptions!Q25
```

How can I create a boolean function to test if `A1` has a reference to the sheet `Assumptions`?

I know if this was simply a constant, I could use: `=+ISNUMBER(SEARCH("assumptions",A1)` but this doesn't work if the cell value is a formula.

Note I am using EXCEL 2010, so `isformula()` won't work

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about two alternative approaches?

1. Do a find a replace on the `=` sign. This will force all of your formulas to text, then you can write a normal formula to do the `SEARCH` or `FIND`. Then reverse the formulas back. I usually do a find all `=` and replace with `^^^` - then just reverse with find all `^^^` and replace with `=`.
2. If the heart of your question is just to find the references, why not use "find" `CTRL+F` ensure that `Look in: Formulas` is elected (under `Options...`), and then use the `Find All` button. This provides a nice list of output.